# extract part of xml from a string

Tags: c#, xml

i have a xml response in string..

```
 string rerricingresponsexml= xmlvalue;
```

the xmlvalue is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Repricing>
  <Flights>
    .....
  </Flights>
</Repricing>
```

Now i want to extract `<Flights> to \</Flights>`

I tried

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(rerricingresponsexml);

        XmlNode headerNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("RePricing");
        if (headerNode != null)
        {
            string headerNodeXml = headerNode.OuterXml;
        }
```

But it says Illegal character in xml..
Any help please..

Comment: Where do you get the Error? When loading the document?

Comment: @Sasidharan: did you try my solution?

Comment: Question might be same, but the provided answers are different...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var flights = xml.DescendantsAndSelf("Flights");
```

It will return `IEnumerable<XElement>`. If you want to get it as string you can use this:

```
string.Concat(flights.Nodes())
```

Comment: Awesome @Hamlet Hakobyan...It worked like honey..

Answer (score 0):

Xml is case-sensitive. Use `Repricing` instead of `RePricing`. Also you should load xml string with [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method. When you using Load method, document tries to load non-existing file:

```
doc.LoadXml(rerricingresponsexml);
XmlNode headerNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Repricing");
```

Also consider to use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for parsing:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(rerricingresponsexml);
var flights = from f in xdoc.Root.Elements("Flights").Elements()
              select new {
                  SearchId = (string)f.Element("SearchId"),
                  Currency = (string)f.Element("Currency"),
                  AdultPrice = (decimal)f.Element("AdultPrice"),
                  // etc
                  Legs = from l in f.Element("LegDetails").Elements()
                         select new {
                             AirLineCode = (string)l.Element("AirLineCode"),
                             FromSector = (string)l.Element("FromSector"),
                             ToSector = (string)l.Element("ToSector")
                             // etc
                         }
              };
```

Comment: its not getting into that..i m getting error in  doc.Load()

Comment: The OP says he gets an error on `.Load`, not on `.SelectSingleNode`. I'm not sure if this would resolve his issue

Comment: i thought its because of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...and i replaced this with null..even though its hitting same error

Comment: @Sasidharan see update - Looad method should be used to load XmlDocument from file. So, document tries to load file with name which is your xml response

Comment: ok is there any other work around for this..

Comment: @Sasidharan what do you mean by workaround? You are using wrong method for loading xml. Use correct one. This is a fix, not workaround

Answer (score 0):

Use LinqToXML ad you will be fine with just two lines of code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(rerricingresponsexml);
string flightDetails= doc.Descendants("Flights").SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

Hope it helps!